# Error while upgrading library commons-collection from version 3.2 to version 4.4

Tags: java, maven, wsdl

In WSDL conversion project, While upgrading library commons-collection from version 3.2 to version 4.4,
I am getting error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate"

I am using commons-configuration-1.6.jar also.
and error is coming at this point:

```
    xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration();

    xmlConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
```

Here XMLConfiguration is in package "org.apache.commons.configuration"

Comment: Have you checked whether this class was removed?

Comment: The package name has changed from commons-collection 3 to 4... "org.apache.commons.collections4.*"...

Comment: yes, I have taken care of this. commons.collections4 is used now in place of commons.collections version 3.2